# Closure compile warningr: [JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY] Property TextEncoder never defined on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

To use the TextEncoder class in a Node.js application I do:

```
const TextEncoder = require("util").TextEncoder;
```

The code works fine, but I get an unwanted warning from the Closure compiler:

```
[JSC_POSSIBLE_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY] Property TextEncoder never defined on ?
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that it doesn't see a definition for the property.   You can either:

- **(a)** provide it via externs:

  https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/externs-and-exports
- **(b)** suppress it with a jsdoc comment on the statement it is reported on:

  ```
  /** @suppress {missingProperties} */
  ```

  The suppress annotation can also be in a `@fileoverview` JSDoc comment at the top the file.

  More details can be found here:

  https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/@suppress-annotations
- **(c)** turn off the warning at the command-line, if you are using the standard command-line tool:

  `--warning_level=QUIET` to turn off all diagnostics

  or by turning of individual diagnostic groups using `--jscomp_off=...` such as `--jscomp_off=missingProperties`

Comment: Thanks. We found a way to add it to the Externs. We didn't want to suppress all the warnings as they often indicate genuine problems.